# Extracting data from Tukey HSD in R

Tags: r, structure, extract

Consider the following piece of toy-code (purely illustrative):

```
y <- data.frame(matrix(c(11,12,13,14,113,124,215,219),nrow=4));
y[,2] <- factor(y[,2]);
aov.result <- aov(y$X1 ~ y$X2, data=y);
thsd.result <- TukeyHSD(aov.result); # Produces NaNs but nevermind
fix(thsd.result)
```

the last command (fix) shows that the thsd.result object is a structure containing a list and nested structure:

```
structure(list(`df$X2` = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("124-113", 
"215-113", "219-113", "215-124", "219-124", "219-215"), c("diff", 
"lwr", "upr", "p adj")))), .Names = "df$X2", class = c("multicomp", 
"TukeyHSD"), orig.call = quote(aov(formula = df$X1 ~ df$X2, data = df)), conf.level =     
0.95, ordered = FALSE);
```

My question is: How would I go about access this structure? I.e. How would I for example get the .Dimnames consisting of the pairs?

Comment: It is just a list. Use `[[.]]` to access the elements as you'd normally in a list. The object this list holds is a matrix: `thsd.result[[1]]`. Then you can access the matrix directly.

Comment: `str(thsd.result)` is better suited for checking the structure than `fix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like this:

```
dimnames(thsd.result[[1]])
```

and this:

```
> rownames(thsd.result[[1]])
[1] "124-113" "215-113" "219-113" "215-124" "219-124" "219-215"
> colnames(thsd.result[[1]])
[1] "diff"  "lwr"   "upr"   "p adj"
```

to get the result just access it using `[[]]`.

See the results printed with:

`thsd.result[[1]]` and `thsd.result[[1]][,1]`

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that. Thanks a lot.